# How to support jQuery Mobile Offline version?

Tags: json, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am making an app using jquery-mobile and phonegap. which parse json data to show the content.

```
{"system":
{
     "name": "Staci",
     "thumb": "image.png"
}
}
```

I want my app like for the first time user will download all jsondata from internet. and will store all the images and information in the device. So from next time user dont have to use internet to see the app. is there any way to do that.
Thanks

Comment: Whichever method you adopt for your solution, for images, store the dataURIs.

Comment: @KazekageGaara didn't quite get what you are saying. but Im trying to download both json file and associated images contains that json in localstorage

Comment: For images, are you planning to download the entire image? I simply meant, you can get the images, get their dataURIs, and store them instead. It'll be lighter, and better.

Comment: @KazekageGaara well dataURI would be awesome. do you know how can I store it

Comment: As a string. That's why it would be lighter as compared to the real image.

Comment: @KazekageGaara please can you give me some example :( some source code would much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can store data in device, and next time you only load data from device don't have use internet to load data. ( I built App Phonegap in android and i use SQLife to store data). Phonegap have API support that.
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#openDatabase